# how to launch apps hidden from the launcher or panel

Tags: command-line, panel

How do I launch an app in such a way that it does not show up in / is hidden from / skips the panel or unity launcher or xfce panel or kde panel etc?

Apps like "stormcloud " weather app are a good example of an ap I'd like to use this technique with.

Thank you.

Comment: since then I've been able to create window rules in KDE to "skip the pager" for certain apps. it's a temporary fix for now on KDE at least.